# Helping understand serialized values

Tags: arrays, wordpress, serialization

I have a database record holding the information below, generated by a wp theme:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:3:{s:2:"id";s:29:"app_i-have";s:4:"type";s:8:"checkbox";s:5:"props";a:4:{s:8:"required";s:1:"0";s:5:"label";s:25:"I have";s:3:"tip";s:0:"";s:7:"options";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:8:"baseline";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:14:"mobile studio";}i:1;a:2:{s:8:"baseline";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:9:"makeup artist";}}}}i:1;a:3:{s:2:"id";s:13:"app_customers";s:4:"type";s:6:"select";s:5:"props";a:4:{s:8:"required";s:1:"0";s:5:"label";s:9:"Customers";s:3:"tip";s:0:"";s:7:"options";a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:8:"baseline";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:7:"Private";}i:1;a:2:{s:8:"baseline";s:1:"0";s:5:"value";s:8:"Business";}}}}}
```

Now i am wondering how i can use this data for a frontend form. 
I would like a form to be generated with the fields that are in the data above, such as:

```
<form>
<label>I have</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="mobile studio">Mobile studio
<input type="checkbox" name="makeup artist">Makeup artist
<label>Customers</label>
<select>
<option name="private">Private</option>
<option name="business">Business</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Anyone who can help me out on something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unserialize data first:

unserialize($serialized_data);

Then just display it and you will see how it seems as an array:

```
$d=unserialize($serialized_data);
var_dump($kk);
```

If the data is valid, you will see array structure and be able to use it inside the form.

Comment: Ok thanks. What would be the best way to get the data from the db? Just a basic SELECT query?

Comment: in which table is it saved? what is the name of the field?

Comment: Hi, it is saved in postmeta table. The field key is va_form.

Comment: then no need to unserialize. Just use this function : $array_data=get_post_meta($post->ID,'va_form',true)

Comment: Thanks, this is however not within a post loop. There is no post_id i guess that i can use within a function. I guess im going to need a SELECT mysql query.

Comment: But how would you find this with SQL query if you don't know its post_id? If there is only 1 va_form in your database, then you can get it and add to this function:  f.e. get_post_meta(223,'va_form',true) .  But if you want to do it with SQL, then use this:  global $wpdb; $serialized=$wpdb->get_val("select meta_value from $wpdb->postmeta where meta_key='va_form'"); $array=unserialize($serialized);

Comment: Thanks, i have 1 va_form indeed:)